# How to know when barcode scanner has finished scanning Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a barcode scanner and I'm using this code:

```
var str = '';

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    var char = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    str += char;
});
```

Which works, but fires the event listener like 15 times. I want to know how to detect when the last one is fired, sin the amount it fires can vary...

Comment: Well does it send any other events? If not, could be a simple timer to wait until it stops.

Comment: Is the barcode scanner basically just a keyboard? Or how does it work?

Comment: Usually you can configure the scanner to send a return at the end.  That would be the most robust way to do this.

Comment: The last one happens when? From what I see you need to figure out a way to detect the last character of your barcode scanner. If you know this you can simply add `if ( e.keyCode === THE_LAST_CHAR_KEYCODE ) { return; }` to the top of your function and you will only capture the last one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If your scanner can be configured to send Enter**, this works:

Keydown with keyCode is deprecated, in favor of the keypress event.

```
window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
       // enter pressed.
    }
    else {
        str += e.key;
    }
});
```

Here's a fiddle to test: https://jsfiddle.net/jmbldwn/nLv9t5k2/6/

**If you can't configure the scanner to send Enter**, you can do this with a timeout, assuming the scanner will send the keys rapidly.  Adjust the timeout to be something just longer than your worst case delay from your scanner.

```
let str = '';
let timer = null;
window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    str += e.key;
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('scanned:', str);
        str = '';   
    }, 500);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jmbldwn/msy5Lovx/4/

Comment: Combined both answers into this one.

Comment: Sorry I forgot about this question because the project I was working on didn't take off. Anyway, from what I remember the scanner sent all the keys rapidly so maybe the tiemout would work. Also, I was going to generate the barcodes myself so maybe the best solution would've been to include a escape character at the end of the code and detect that. If you want, include that into your answer. I'm marking it as correct anyway, thanks!